# What is a vacuously valid argument?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In addition is there some way to show an argument is vacuously valid using semantic tableaux?

Here is an example of a vacuously valid argument:

```
R
Q⇒P
¬P
R⇒(Q⊻P)
∴S
```

Here is it's truth table:
[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Or are you referring to an argument of form $\bot \vDash \varphi$ that is [valid](https://iep.utm.edu/val-snd/) ?

Comment: No, I mean a vacuously valid argument. I don't know if they are both the same thing. Here is a source showing multiple usages of this phrase. https://imgur.com/a/IPxkfq7

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Added :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've added the truth table as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vacuously valid argument is one that is **valid just because the premises are unsatisfiable** (= can not all be simultaneously true).
Remember that an argument is valid iff every interpretation that makes all premises true also makes the conclusion true, or equivalently, there is no interpretation that makes all premises true but the conclusion false. Now if there is no interpretation to make all premises true to begin with (= the premises are unsatisfiable), then we don't even need to look at the conclusion to determine the validity of the argument, and this is when the argument is vacuously true. In fact, from an unsatisfiable set of premises we can infer *any* conclusion. This is known as the law of ex falso quodlibet aka principle of explosion.

In your example, the premises have $R$ which entails either $Q$, which in turn entails $P$, or $P$, both of which contradict the premise $\neg P$. Hence there is no way to satisfy the premises, as you can see in the truth table, where there is no row in which all premises simulateously have a $1$.

In a tableau, the conclusion being irrelevant for the validity of the argument is reflected in that **the (negated) conclusion doesn't need to be evaluated in order reach a closed tree**: If the premises are unsatisfiable, then you will be able to reach contradictions on every branch just by applying rules on the premises, leaving the conclusion assumption untouched.

In a truth table, where you determine validity of an argument by veryifing  that there is no line wich has $1$ for all premises but a $0$ for the conclusoin, a vacuously valid argument will have **no rows with $1$ for all the premises** to begin with -- this is precisely what it means for a set of formulas to be unsatisfiable.

Comment: +1. Great answer. Could you clarify the meaning of closed tree and how can you reach contradictions on every branch ?

Comment: A tableau branch is closed iff it contains occurrences of $P$ and $\neg P$ for some formula $P$. A tableau tree is closed iff all its branches are closed. Analatic tableaus are introduced in e.g. Smullyan (2009) *Logical labyriths*.

Comment: I understand, now. Thank you, @lemontree.

Answer (score 2):

A [valid argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Arguments) is an argument where it is impossible that all the premise are true and the conclusion is false.

Your example above has a set of premise that is inconsistent (or unsatisfiable).

Thus there is no way to find a situation (for propositional calculus: a truth assignment, or valuation) that satisfies all the premises and falsify the conclusion.

This means that the above definition of valid argument applies "vacuously".

See also [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation): "from inconsistent premises everything follows".

> How to show that the above argument is valid with semantic tableaux ?

As usual: build a tableaux with the premises and the negation of the conclusion: with inconsistent premises it will work for a conclusion whatever.